# MongoDB Facet results formatting

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a query construction with $facet, that return results in this format:

```
{price_now: [
   { _id: 'apple', price_now: 1.02 },
   { _id: 'melon', price_now: 3.18 },
   { _id: 'cherry', price_now: 2.57 }],
price_15m: [
   { _id: 'apple', price_15m: 1.08 },
   { _id: 'melon', price_15m: 3.12 },
   { _id: 'cherry', price_15m: 2.82 }],
price_30m: [
   { _id: 'apple', price_30m: 1.05 },
   { _id: 'melon', price_30m: 3.04 },
   { _id: 'cherry', price_30m: 2.94 }]
```

How i can get result in this format?:

```
{ _id: 'apple', price_now: 1.02, price_15m: 1.08, price_30m: 1.05 },
{ _id: 'melon', price_now: 3.18, price_15m: 3.12, price_30m: 3.04 },
{ _id: 'cherry', price_now: 2.57, price_15m: 2.82, price_30m: 2.94 }
```

The full query looks like this:

```
var today = new Date();
var shift_15m = new Date(today.getTime()-15*60*1000);
var shift_30m = new Date(today.getTime()-30*60*1000);

food.aggregate( [
    {
        $facet: {
            price_now: [
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$name",
                        price_now: {$last: "$price"}
                    }
                }
            ],
            price_15m: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        date: { "$lte": shift_15m }
                    }
                }, {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$name",
                        price_5m: {$last: "$price"}
                    }
                }
            ],
            price_30m: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        date: { "$lte": shift_30m }
                    }
                }, {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$name",
                        price_30m: {$last: "$price"}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

I need to get prices for each product for different time interval in one query. Maybe your know a better and faster method to get prices from different times.
My MongoDB version is v3.6.0. I use mongoose in Node.js App.

Comment: Add a `$match` stage before `$facet` to limit the products between today and your highest range. Do you always have fixed number of products being returned in each time category ? Just trying to understand so we can format them.

Comment: @Veeram I store the prices only for last 6 hour. The new products can be added to DB some times.

Comment: Okay I've added an answer. See if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be efficient based on your use case but one can merge the arrays in the following way from facets operation.

Make sure all the facets categories are sorted by name and each row in all arrays contains the same product.

You can then `$zip` all the facets categories first and then `$reduce` each category to combine all the different prices and repeat for all products.

You can add the below stage after your facet stage.

```
{"$project":{
  "data":{
    "$map":{
      "input":{"$zip":{"inputs":["$price_10s","$price_30s", "$price_30m"],"useLongestLength":true}},
      "as":"item",
      "in":{
        "$reduce":{
          "input":"$$item",
          "initialValue":{},
          "in":{"$mergeObjects":["$$this","$$value"]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

Comment: I got this error: '$zip found a non-array expression in input: "price_30m"'
code: 34468,
codeName: 'Location34468'

Comment: oh sorry it should be `$price_30m` in zip. Fixing

Comment: I post full construction in next comment. Please, check it. @Veeram

Answer (score 0):

@Veeram, here is the full construction.

```
food.aggregate( [
    {
        $facet: {
            price_now: [
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$market_name",
                        price_now: {$last: "$my_time_stamp"}
                    }
                }
            ],
            price_5m: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        my_time_stamp: { "$lte": shift_5m }
                    }
                }, {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$market_name",
                        price_5m: {$last: "$my_time_stamp"}
                    }
                }
            ],
            price_15m: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        my_time_stamp: { "$lte": shift_15m }
                    }
                }, {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$market_name",
                        price_15m: {$last: "$my_time_stamp"}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }, {
        "$project":{
            "data":{
                "$map":{
                    "input":{"$zip":{"inputs":["$price_now","$price_5m", "price_15m"],"useLongestLength":true}},
                    "as":"item",
                    "in":{
                        "$reduce":{
                            "input":"$$item",
                            "initialValue":{},
                            "in":{"$mergeObjects":["$$this","$$value"]}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
         console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(result)
    };
});
```

Comment: Try `{"$zip":{"inputs":["$price_now","$price_5m", "$price_15m"],"useLongestLength":true}}`